# Node.js module install location

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Is it possible to install a node_module outside of the node_modules folder?

For example: I'm trying to install gulp and I would like to have gulp in a separate folder in my workspace

```
workspace
|-gulp
|-node_modules
|  |- ...
|  |- ...
```

Comment: Usually all of a project's dependencies will reside within the project folder. What exactly are you trying to accomplish by installing modules to a non-standard location? Your project will not be able to access the `gulp` package if it is not installed in the correct location.

Comment: You can fork the github repository and `require('./gulp')` instead of `require('gulp')` but doing so would be _extremely_ ill-advised, since you would have to commit your dependency with your application, which is a big anti-pattern, and serves no purpose. Whatever the reason you want to do this, it's probably not good enough, and you'd be much better off following standard practices for the sake of usability and portability.

Comment: @Lix I'm trying to keep a certain folder structure. I was wondering if it was possible to do this at all.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I will :). Thank you very much.

Comment: If you're following a tutorial, it's possible you misunderstood. A lot of projects will put gulp _tasks_ under `workspace/gulp` but _not the dependency itself_

Comment: You might be able to setup the folder structure you want but you would have to keep in mind that your project is deviating from the expected structure of most if not **all** node projects. As patrick mentioned in the comments - the reasons for doing this most likely don't outweigh the benefits of adhering to conventions of the language you are using.

Comment: @Lix. You're right. I'll try and stick to the convention. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is *possible*, but *extremely* ill-advised.

You could hypothetically [fork the github repository](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp) and `require('./gulp')` instead of `require('gulp')` and doing so would give you the following *fun and exciting challenges* to face:

- You would no longer have the power of [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) available through [`npm`](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning). You and consumers of your application would be locked into the exact (and likely arbitrary) commit of `gulp` that you decide to fork, and...
- You would have to make a pull-request for any and all updates to your application's `gulp` dependency.
- You would have to commit your dependency with your project.<sup>**1**</sup> This only serves to unnecessarily bloat your application.
- When loading your application onto a remote service with limited resources (such as a limitation of memory or disk space), you'd be wasting valuable real-estate potential for performance enhancements such as caching, etc.

If all of the above is okay with you, then by all means feel free to organize your application's structure that way. No one's stopping you!

While you're at it, I urge you to get checked for head injuries as well.

<sub>**1.** I have never done this before, but I would assume you'd have to purge the `.git` directory within `workspace/gulp` before you'd even be able to do this, which can be a hassle all of its own.</sub>